# Regex: How can I check if any process is taking 80% or more CPU in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have CPU process output in a string variable. Now I want to check if any process is occupying 80% or more. Please help me with the regex in Python. command output is like this:`CPU utilization for five seconds: 81%/0%; one minute: 30%; five minutes: 26%
         PID Runtime(ms)     Invoked      uSecs   5Sec   1Min   5Min TTY Process 
           3        6765         291      23247 60.24%  8.07%  1.72%   3 SSH Process

         126       22753       14985       1518  4.97%  0.88%  0.43%   0 IP Input

         219      424447      390715       1086  1.84%  1.73%  1.66%   0 MMA DP TIMER

          70      263766       25673      10274  0.96%  1.02%  1.00%   0 Per-Second Jobs

          74      624912     2986593        209  0.80%  2.17%  2.39%   0 Ethernet Msec Ti 
         125      198586      753349        263  0.80%  0.82%  0.80%   0 IP ARP Retry Age`

Output should be something like- "a Process is using 80% or more CPU"

Comment: Please code indent your output data for it to be readable. (add 4 spaces before each line of click the `{}` button after selecting data)

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Regular expressions are bad at arithmetic. Consider just splitting your input data into columns with `split()`.

Comment: Output should be something like- 
"a Process is using 80% or more CPU"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io), so you dont have to regexp yourself:

```
>>> for proc in psutil.process_iter():
...     procInfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username', 'cpu_percent'])
...     if procInfo['cpu_percent'] >= 80:
...             print('...')
```

Comment: Here, this script is getting output from a Cisco Router command. There psutil is not supported actually so I have will have to go regex way only. thank you